# Liferay, how to set workflow for page scope

Tags: liferay

How can you set a scope for a workflow in Liferay Portal 6 CE? I can see you can set it up at a portal level and at the 'Default' scope, but I wish to be more specific than that.

e.g.

> Documents -> Policy = Policy Workflow (for Document Library Document)
>   Documents -> Guidelines = Guideline Workflow (for Document Library Document)

If I go to 'Workflow Configuration' then change the scope to anything other than 'Default', I get the following message, even though I am an administrator (using 'Bruno Admin').

> You do not have the required permissions to access this application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Liferay 6.0 you can only configure workflow per community+content type (e.g. for the complete DocumentLibrary in a community). For more you'd need to customize Liferay through code/plugin or wait for a new version (I don't know if it's going to be implemented in 6.1, you might want to check this in trunk.